# Attach Angular2 Component to existing element without replacing content

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some problem with migrate ng1 app to ng2. We load our ng1 app dynamicly and attach to body or html tag  of the page with inline directives inside. See this example - [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tmk9MCq0snoW8AllHgp3?p=preview) .

After page load, we just do

```
angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

Directives are "alive" now.

But with ng2 i don't know how to do it properly. If we bootstrap component with body selector, it will replace all content of the page. We can add ... into body, but our "inline" directives still outside of this tag, somewhere in user content, so they will not be compiled.

The only way i can manage it now is to bootstrap every "inline" directive separately. But 
    bootstrap(MyDirective);
will bootstrap only first matched element on page, so i need to "clone" directive class and dynamically set strict selector for it:

```
var someDirective = (function (_super) {
    __extends(someDirective , _super);
    function someDirective () {
        _super.call(this);
    }

    return someDirective;
})(myDirective); //extend directive class
someDirective['annotations'] = [  //set annotations
    new Component({
        selector: "div[myDirective='1']", //here we go
    }),
    new View({
        template: 'myDirective.html'
    })
];

bootstrap(someDirective);
```

And it works - [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1imNdzqRuqJEf61u10jX?p=preview). But it just doesn't feel right. Maybe there more correct way to do such thing?

Thanks!

Comment: If I understood correctly you want a Component which contains N-th directives? If that's what you want, you just have to add `directives` to your `View` annotation.